# Import \mathbbit{q} from stix

Tags: symbols, amsmath, stix

I am trying to import the following symbol

```
\mathbbit{q}
```

from stix library,

[image]

see the following code, please:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\newcommand*\qq{%
\text{%
\fontencoding{LS1}%
\fontfamily{stixbb}%
\fontseries{\textmathversion}%
\fontshape{n}%
\selectfont\symbol{`q}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\textmathversion{\csname textmv@\math@version\endcsname}
\newcommand*\textmv@normal{m}
\newcommand*\textmv@bold{b}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  $\qq$ {\boldmath$\qq$}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, there is no

```
ls1stixbbit.fd
```

font in the /stix folder, only

```
ls1stixbb.fd
```

is available. Therefore, I am able to create only non-italic or bold q:

[image]

Is there any way of importing italic, black-boarded q from stix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\fontshape{it}`: the same `.fd` file defines several font shapes.

The code can be simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}

\newcommand*\qq{%
  \text{\usefont{LS1}{stixbb}{\textmathversion}{n}q}%
}
\newcommand*\qqit{%
  \text{\usefont{LS1}{stixbb}{\textmathversion}{it}q}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\textmathversion{\csname textmv@\math@version\endcsname}
\newcommand*\textmv@normal{m}
\newcommand*\textmv@bold{b}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\qq$ {\boldmath$\qq$}

$\qqit$ {\boldmath$\qqit$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ egreg:Thank you very much for your code and explanation...